# Durandal Google Analtyics Tracking

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, durandal

I'm using Durandal 1.2 and the [Durandal Router Plugin](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api#module/router) and wanting to track page views in the SPA through Google Analytics:
`window._gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash]`

I know I could listen for the hashchange event or even hook into via [Sammy](http://sammyjs.org). I'd rather not do that given Durandal is currently being [rewritten](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/FuZStbu1f2k) to remove the dependency on Sammy.

My question is, is there a way to set this up using the Durandal Router Plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at `onNavigationComplete` in the router. You could override that to do your analytics:

```
// Store reference to router's onNavigationComplete so you can call it
var onNavigationComplete = router.onNavigationComplete;

router.onNavigationComplete = function (routeInfo, params, module) {
    // Run the default onNavigationComplete
    onNavigationComplete.call(this, routeInfo, params, module);

    // Analytics!
    window._gaq.push(['_trackPageview', location.pathname + location.search + location.hash]
};
```

Obviously you'll need to do this somewhere very early in your application's lifecycle, such as in your `main.js`.

Answer (score 4):

You could also attach to the `navigation complete` event, so that you don't have to store the router's original function.

```
//Update anaytics whenever the router navigates
router.on('router:navigation:complete', function(instance, instruction) {
    window._gaq.push(['_trackPageview', instruction.fragment]);
});
```